# SQL Server remove leading 0's and all characters after digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey I'm a java dev guys so I normally don't do this so bear with me.

I have a column in a table that looks like

```
Column
001 - test
012 - test 2
```

I need those values to look like like below when I do a select:

```
1
12
...
...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Always a 3 digit number? Or just any digit number before the dash?

Comment: it could possibly be four with the 0 included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to convert the leading digits to a number.  I would recommend:

```
select cast(left(column, patindex('%[^0-9]%', column) as decimal(38))
```

I chose decimal 38 because it is the largest exact numeric value (although `int` seems sufficient for your purposes).

You can also do this by removing initial zeros and leaving the result as a string:

```
select stuff(left(column, patindex('%[^0-9]%', column),
             1, patindex('%[^0]%', column) - 1, '')
```

And, if you know it is *always* three digits:

```
select cast(left(column, 3) as int)
```

and for a string:

```
select cast(cast(left(column, 3) as int) as varchar(3))
```